# handling a specific exception type

Tags: aspectj

I've defined two AfterThrowing advices to handle exceptions with the same pointcut.

```
@AfterThrowing(pointcut="...", throwing="ex")
public void method1(Exception ex) {}


@AfterThrowing(pointcut="...", throwing="ex")
public void method2(GatewayException ex) {}
```

Is there a way for me to prevent the generic method1 being executed if the exception is a GatewayException?

Any ideas greatly appreciated

C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be the easiest to check the instance of the exception inside the advice body and return early if it's of the more specific exception type:

```java
@AfterThrowing(pointcut="...", throwing="ex")
public void method1(Exception ex) {
    if (ex instanceof GatewayException) {
        return;
    }
    // handle the more generic Exception case
}


@AfterThrowing(pointcut="...", throwing="ex")
public void method2(GatewayException ex) {
    // handle the more specific GatewayException
}
```

I know you expected a solution based on some AspectJ language construct, but the thing is, there's no such construct.

Comment: Yeah I was hoping to avoid instanceof but I think you're right.